# Admob Ads. TimeoutException. Error waiting for future. Failed to load Ad 3

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I am trying to implement AdMob banner ads. Test ID is working fine. But for my Ad ID its showing the error posting under logcat.

MAINACTIVITY

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "MY_APP_ID");
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

XML

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_ID" />
```

MANIFEST

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="MY_APP_ID"/>
```

PROJECT.GRADLE

```
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

APP.GRADLE

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
```

LOGCAT

> 10-10 15:47:21.430 29883-30587/? E/Ads: Error waiting for future.
>       java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.af.get(:com.google.android.gms@14366007@14.3.66 (020304-213742215):18)
>           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.g.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366007@14.3.66 (020304-213742215):11)
>           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.c.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366007@14.3.66 (020304-213742215):36)
>           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.c.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366007@14.3.66 (020304-213742215):169)
>           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.f.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366007@14.3.66 (020304-213742215):1)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>        Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.m.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>   10-10 15:47:22.280 13964-13979/com.ashleytobeybuttons.whosyourdaddyboy I/Ads: No fill from ad server.
>   10-10 15:47:22.300 13964-13964/com.ashleytobeybuttons.whosyourdaddyboy W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3

Comment: Is it fixed now?